# How to write this symbol for a sigma algebra?

Tags: math-mode

How to write two below symbol in picture for a sigma algebra in latex?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are standard euler calligraphic and fraktur fonts

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{eufrak} % you don't need this if you have \usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\EuScript{M}$
$\mathfrak{M}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Loading the package `euscript` with the `mathcal` (`mathscr`) option will replace the `\mathcal` alphabet (define a new one `\mathscr`).